# MAMP Pro: Unable to access WordPress site by URL

Tags: wordpress, mamp-pro

I'm working on a WordPress site locally on my Mac. I was trying to configure MAMP Pro to work so I could test on the iOS simulators.

After doing some research I attempted to update the WordPress Home URL and the WordPress Site URL to my IP Address. Once I made the changes I was unable to access my website.

I logged onto phpMyAdmin to restore the WordPress Home URL and WordPress Site URL within the `wp_options` table. The issue is now that when I try to access the WordPress site using the arrow within the MAMP Pro app (see attached screenshot), it states that site cannot access.

When I try to type the name (tangoniche) with the port number (8888), it gives me the same error. When I enable the IP address option it does work. How do I restore access to using `localhost:8888` or `tangoniche:8888`?

[image]

Comment: What do you have in your `siteurl` and `home` entries in `wp_options` table at the moment?

Comment: http://tangoniche:8888 for both URL's. This is based on another Wordpress instance that is working as expected.